# cheating on me with his client

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand the phrase "cheating on me with his client" as "(he and his client together cheating on me (because they had improper relationship like affairs)."  Am I on the right track?

> Dear Chump Lady,

I’ve been divorced from my lying cheating ex since January 2016 after I found out he was **cheating on me with his client**. At the time we lived in a different state and shortly after our separation (June 2015), he moved in with his ladylovewhore and I moved back home to the great state of Texas.

Source: [Chump Lady](https://www.chumplady.com/2016/09/ubt-respect-relationship-ow/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "cheat on" somebody is an idiomatic way of saying that someone betrayed their partner (eg a marriage partner) by engaging in some kind of relationship with someone else. That could be a sexual relationship, but many would consider that flirting with another person, or having an 'emotional affair' to be tantamount to cheating.

So the answer is yes - "cheating on my with his client" meant that the person's partner had some kind of affair with someone who had been their client.

Answer (score 1):

#### It's saying he had an adulterous relationship with his client.

That sentence is saying that the woman's husband had an adulterous relationship with a client of his. It wasn't like adultery, it was straight-up adultery - the dude in question was cheating on his wife by having sexual relations with his client.

Additionally, that article seems to use quite a bit of impolite language, because it was written by the jilted ex-spouse of the adulterous husband, and it's deliberately insulting the "other woman" by calling her a whore; I would not recommend doing that. Even if she was actually working in that field, the polite term to use is "sex worker".